# How to sort an object based on the key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose i have an object `obj1= {key1:[1,2,3],key2:[333,11],key3:[9938,33,0,39,2]}`
How to sort this by length of value array. I tried using Lodash method but that didnt worked.
Required output

`obj1= {key3:[9938,33,0,39,2],key1:[1,2,3],key2:[333,11]}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a disclaimer: JavaScript objects are typically considered to be **unordered** key/value pairs. While recent versions of the ECMAScript specification do stipulate how object properties are ordered, the rules are complex, and it remains good advice to not rely on object order unless you know what you're doing.

That being said, you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get your desired result:

```js
const o = {
  key1: [1,2,3],
  key2: [333,11], 
  key3: [9938,33,0,39,2]
};

const r = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(o).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2.length - v1.length)
);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

test it

```js
let obj2={}
        let obj1= {key3:[9938,33,0,39,2],key1:[1,2,3],key2:[333,11]}
        Object.keys(obj1)
        .sort((a,b)=>{
            if (obj1[a].length>obj1[b].length) {
                return -1
            }
            if (obj1[a].length<obj1[b].length) {
                return 1
            }
            return 0
        })
        .map(x=>{
            obj2[x]=obj1[x]
        })
        console.log(obj2);
```